# json_serializable - Specify custom path for generated files

Tags: flutter

The `json_serializable` package discussed [here](https://flutter.io/json/) generates `class.g.dart` files, but I'd like to keep my generated files in a separate path.

I've attempted creating a directory `generated_json/` and specifying `part 'generated_json/class.g.dart';` in my `class.dart` file. This doesn't seem to have any effect, the files are still generated in the same directory as `class.dart`.

Is there a way to specify a custom path?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this is not possible currently with `json_serializable`. Discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/issues/306) on the `json_serializable` wiki.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible using build.yaml, refer to this [answer](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/306#issuecomment-1126651863)

Step 1:

- create **build.yaml**, place in root project folder

  ```
  targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      source_gen:combining_builder:
        options:
          build_extensions:
            '^lib/pathtofile/{{}}.dart': 'lib/generated/{{}}.g.dart'
  ```

Step 2:

- inside lib/classes , create your model annotated with @JsonSeriazable(), i will give a bit example

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part '../generated/product.g.dart'; // generated file will stored inside lib/generated folder

@JsonSerializable()
class Product {
  final int? id;
  final String? name;
  final int? price;

  Product({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.price,
  });

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ProductFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ProductToJson(this);
}
```

Step 3:

- run build runner

```
flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```