# chopper - Specify custom path for generated files

Tags: flutter, code-generation, chopper

The [chopper](https://pub.dev/packages/chopper) library is similar to the Retrofit library in native Android development. It utilizes the [build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner) package to generate code through the `flutter pub run build_runner build` command. By default, the generated files are placed in the same directory as the source files. I want to put all generated files in the lib/generated directory. While it is possible to do so for the json_serializable package, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303764/json-serializable-specify-custom-path-for-generated-files), I have been unsuccessful trying to configure the build.yaml file for the chopper library. The following configuration has not worked:

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      source_gen|combining_builder:
        options:
          build_extensions:
            '^lib/{{}}.dart': 'lib/generated/{{}}.g.dart'
      chopper_generator:
        options:
          build_extensions:
            '^lib/{{}}.dart': 'lib/generated/{{}}.chopper.dart'
```

How can I properly configure the build.yaml file for the chopper library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This possibility has been just implemented with the latest version of the chopper_generator: https://github.com/lejard-h/chopper/issues/443